# How can I type a test in order to see if my function works?

Tags: c, pointers

Here's my function which takes a pointer to an integer.

```c
void ft_ft(int *nbr)
{
    *nbr = 42;
}
```

Can someone explain me how to write a test for this function?

Comment: Call `ft_ft` with a pointer to an `int`, and check that you got 42 in that `int` when the function returns ?

Comment: Do you intend to use a test framework (and then which one) of do you just want to write some code using that function?

Comment: I want to write some code using that function to see if it works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a call and an assertion (which will only be active in debug builds):

```c
#include <assert.h>

void ft_ft(int *nbr) {
    *nbr = 42;
}

int main(void) {
    int foo = 0;
    
    ft_ft(&foo);       // call the function

    assert(foo == 42); // exit with an error message if foo is not 42
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of testing is to find bugs.

In all except very “small” or simple functions, it is beyond our abilities to prove a function works: Most functions are too complicated for mathematical proof without great effort or have more cases than we can test. For example, a function that computes *x*<sup>*y*</sup> given two 64-bit `double` values *x* and *y* has 2<sup>128</sup> cases to test, and that is more than we can test exhaustively.

Therefore, testing is usually not done to “see if a function works.” We want to find bugs, not to find working code. Another reason to frame the hunt this way is human psychology: If you tell a human to see if a function works, that makes them more likely to find that the function works rather than motivating them to hunt for bugs. This is more important than some people realize: A **positive** test is one that finds a bug. Failing to find a bug is a **negative** result. We are trying to find positive results.

To test your function, think of ways it can fail.

Before you know how a function can fail, you must know what it should do. As you described your function, it “takes pointer to an integer.” You did not say what it does. Judging by the sample code, it sets the `int` that the arguments points to to 42. But that is judging by the sample code, which is what we are testing for bugs, not by the specification of the function. You need a complete specification of the function, such as:

- The function `ft_ft` accepts an argument of type `int *` (pointer to `int`, not just “pointer to integer) and has return type `void`.
- The argument is required to point to an object. There is no specification for the function’s behavior if the argument is null.
- The function sets the pointed-to `int` to 42 and returns with no other effects.

Now suppose somebody gave you an object module containing this function and no source code. How would you test the function?

To start, for this function, you must pass it an `int *` that points to an `int`. With some functions, they might be defined to behave in a certain way if passed a null pointer. However, with the specification above, there is no definition for that case, so we do not need to test it.

Then here are some things to test:

- Is the function actually changing the `int` we pass it? Test: Set an `int` to zero, pass its address to the function, and test whether its value is not 42 when the function returns.
- Does the function add 42 instead of setting the `int` to 42? Test: Set an `int` to another value, say 1, pass its address to the function, and test whether its value is not 42 when the function returns.
- Does the function actually operate on a whole `int`, not just a `short` or  `char`? Test: Set an `int` to a value that is different in each byte from the `int` containing 42, and test whether its value is not 42 when the function returns.
- Does the function work for “edge” cases? Set `int` to `INT_MIN` and test whether its value is not 42 when the function returns. Test `INT_MAX`. If your C implementation supports trap values for `int`, test a trap value.
- Does the function change anything else? How about stuff near the `int` it is passed? Test: Embed the `int` in an array of other `int`, set them all to zero, call the function, and test whether any part of the array other than the `int` changed. Repeat with values other than zero and with each element of the array containing a different value from other elements.
- Does the function change anything else in memory, maybe stuff not near the `int`? There is not usually an easy way to test this, but you might examine the object module containing the function to see if it contains references to any external identifiers.